# Finding the limiting distribution $n\min(X_1, \dots , X_n)$ with uniformly distributed $X_i$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

> Find the limiting distribution of $nY_n$ where $Y_n = \min(X_1, ..., X_n)$ and $X_1, ..., X_n\sim \operatorname{unif}(0,2)$ are uniformly distributed random variables.

Here is what I did:

$$P(nY_n > x) = P(Y_n > x/n) = (P(X_1 > x/n))^n = \left(\int_{x/n}^2 \frac{1}{2} dx\right)^n = \left(1 - \frac{y}{2n}\right)^n$$

As $n \to \infty$, this probability converges to $e^{-y/2}$

And the distribution would be $$ 1- e^{-y/2} $$ which is $\operatorname{Exp}(1/2)$.

Let me know if I made any mistakes, I am simply checking if I did this correctly.

Comment: A key point is missing: $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent, is this correct?

Comment: Looks OK to me!

Comment: Thanks guys. And yes to Behaviour, I forgot to write it. Thanks for the reminder.